# bash - grabbing the partitions of a hive table using grep and regex

Tags: regex, bash, hive, grep, hive-partitions

I am trying to get the partition column names of a hive table in bash using grep and regex. I am trying this:

```
hive -e 'show create table employees'  | grep -E 'PARTITIONED BY (.*)'
```

This is giving me the result like: `PARTITIONED BY (`

How do I have to modify my command to grab this part:

`PARTITIONED BY (
  year char(4),
  month char(2))`

**The end goal for me is to grab all the partition columns into variables or array so that I can use them later. If there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do, I am open to that as well.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
hive -e 'describe formatted employees' | \
  awk '/Partition/{p=1; next} /Detailed/{p=0} p' | \
    grep -oE '^[[:alnum:]_]+'
```

The `describe formatted employees` will yield a better formatted output describing the table,  `awk '/Partition/{p=1; next} /Detailed/{p=0} p'` will extract the block of text that is between `Partition` and `Detailed` excluding the matching lines and `grep -oE '^[[:alnum:]_]+'` will fetch only those words that are at the start of the lines and only contain letters or digits. If there can only be letters replace `[:alnum:]` with `[:alpha:]`.